# Can't center Navigation Drawer items vertically

Tags: android, android-listview, navigation-drawer

Main activity layout (removed the irrelevant elements):

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black"

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_relative_in_drawer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/black" >

        // some more elements ...

    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/drawer_main"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#80000000"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="10dp" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

drawer_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawerItemTextView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" >

</TextView>
```

The list items are aligned to the center horizontally now, but not vertically.

What should i modify to center them vertically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your drawer item to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/frag1_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>
```

then try, it is working for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#eeeeee" >
    </FrameLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#333333"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="50dp"
   android:orientation="horizontal" >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center|left"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textColor="#FB9200" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

drawer_item.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="a" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

Probably you should change the gravity of items to:

```
android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
```