# Navigation Drawer how to set Gravity for items

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

as the title described ; I need to set gravity for these items down below is the picture ; ( i read [Can't center Navigation Drawer items vertically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30643313/cant-center-navigation-drawer-items-vertically) but it didnt work )

my navigation drawer code :

```
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/activity_nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
    />
```

[image]

Comment: You can create style for it. For reference you can check this - http://stackoverflow.com/a/33140661/2128166

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34329756/1462770

Comment: i used    
 <style name="NavigationViewStyle">
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
        <item name="android:layout_gravity">center</item>
    </style>

but the items text is still on the right , i need it to appear from left

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by setting theme to navigation menu

```
 <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeToolbar.NavigationView"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/inverse_color"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/inverse_color"
    app:itemBackground="@drawable/selector_navigation"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/activity_home_nav_header"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_home_drawer" />
```

Create a style as follows

```
<style name="ThemeToolbar.NavigationView">
    <item name="android:listDivider">@color/inverse_color</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/inverse_color</item>
    <item name="listPreferredItemPaddingRight">50dp</item>
</style>
```